# How C# insert into database fields that contain space and slash

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0

I have field in database like client address, client name,per/hour, master(admin)

I used like

```
string strInsert = "INSERT INTO testdb.testtable([client address], [client name],per/hour) Values(@[client address], @[client name],@per/hour,@master(admin));"

cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[client address]", strclientaddress); 
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[client name]", strclientname); 
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per/hour", strperhour);
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@master(admin)", strmasteradmin);
```

--> Not working

Then changed to this

```
string strInsert = "INSERT INTO testdb.testtable([client address], [client name],per/hour,master(admin) Values([@client address], [@client name],@per/hour,@master(admin));"

cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@client address]", strclientaddress); 
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@client name]", strclientname); 
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per/hour", strperhour);
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@master(admin)", strmasteradmin);
```

--> Still Not Working

then changed to this

```
    string strInsert = "INSERT INTO testdb.testtable('client address', 'client name','per/hour') Values(@'client address', @'client name,@'per/hour',@'master(admin)');"

cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@'client address'", strclientaddress); 
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@'client name'", strclientname); 
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@'per/hour'", strperhour);
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@'master(admin)'", strmasteradmin);
```

--> Still Not Working

then changed to this

```
string strInsert = "INSERT INTO testdb.testtable('client address', 'client name','per/hour', 'master(admin)') Values('@client address', '@client name,'@per/hour','@master(admin)');"

cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("'@client address'", strclientaddress); 
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("'@client name'", strclientname); 
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("'@per/hour'", strperhour);
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("'@master(admin)'", strmasteradmin);
```

--> Still Not working

I used MySQL database version 5.6

Does anyone know how to insert into field such above through C#.net?
How c# handle these paramaters?

Comment: Not exactly sure but isn't there a MySQL driver that abstracts using sql strings to access the db?

Comment: yes already using MySQL driver, but still not working.

Comment: here is the answer : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/55c565d9-ca12-4bfa-abf0-75418027811d/how-to-insert-field-with-space-and-forward-slash?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 0):

how about this one

string strInsert = @"INSERT INTO testdb.testtable('client address', 'client name','per/hour') Values('client address', 'client name,'per/hour','master(admin)');";